# How can I call a key that is wrapped in qoutes inside of an object in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using vue js and trying to call a value from an object using props.

I have this code to call the prop

```
<HeroAppearance 
      :eyeColor="HeroInfo.appearance.eye-color" 
      :gender="HeroInfo.appearance.gender" 
      :hairColor="HeroInfo.appearance.hair-color"
      :height="HeroInfo.appearance.height[0]"
      :race="HeroInfo.appearance.race"
      :weight="HeroInfo.appearance.weight[0]"
      />
```

and props in my component show

```
props: {
      eyeColor: String,
      gender: String,
      hairColor: String,
      height: String,
      race: String,
      weight: String
  }
```

the object I am getting back has both eye-color and hair-color are wrapped in qoutes like this and all values show except for eye-color and hair-color, which show as NaN when the page is loaded

```
{
"eye-color": "Blue"
gender: "Male"
"hair-color": "No Hair"
height: Array [ "6'3", "191 cm" ]
race: "Icthyo Sapien"
}
```

when I load the page I get these 2 errors in console. Could anyone help me to understand what is going on?

```
Property or method "color" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.
```

and

```
Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "eyeColor". Expected String with value "NaN", got Number with value NaN.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call your objects that are hyphenated using this syntax below

```
HeroInfo.appearance['hair-color']
HeroInfo.appearance['eye-color']
```

Comment: @JaySnel While that fix avoids the error, the underlying problem still exists: using camelCase in an HTML attribute.

Comment: @terrymorse is correct that he should use camelCase. But I made the assumption `HeroInfo` was coming from an external API and he cannot mutate it directly.

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing a camelCase vs. kebab-case conflict.

`eyeColor` is camelCase, while `eye-color` is kebab-case.

The [Vue.js Guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Casing-camelCase-vs-kebab-case) says to use camelCase for props, but kebab-case within HTML:

> HTML attribute names are case-insensitive, so browsers will interpret any uppercase characters as lowercase. That means when you’re using in-DOM templates, camelCased prop names need to use their kebab-cased (hyphen-delimited) equivalents.

This change should fix the problem:

```html
<HeroAppearance 
      :eye-color="HeroInfo.appearance.eyeColor" 
      :gender="HeroInfo.appearance.gender" 
      :hair-color="HeroInfo.appearance.hairColor"
      :height="HeroInfo.appearance.height[0]"
      :race="HeroInfo.appearance.race"
      :weight="HeroInfo.appearance.weight[0]"
      />
```